# Apache returns error 403 from varnish

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish

Varnish is installed properly and seems to work fine on the same machine with apache. It passes content from backend but caching doesnt work.

Header looks like below:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden => 
Date => Thu, 19 May 2016 05:10:10 GMT
Server => Apache
Vary => Accept-Encoding
Content-Type => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-Varnish => 218
Age => 0
Via => 1.1 varnish-v4
Connection => close
```

log from /usr/local/apache/domlogs/domain.com

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [19/May/2016:00:31:23 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403
```

apache error_log

```
[Thu May 19 00:54:45 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] client denied by server configuration: /home/vps/public_html/domain.com/
[Thu May 19 00:54:45 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] client denied by server configuration: /home/vps/public_html/domain.com/page-not-found
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is public IP of my vps where both apache and varnisch are installed.

/etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;
import directors;

backend default {
    .host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; (my public IP)
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
#    IP forwarding.
     if (req.restarts == 0) {
         if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
          set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
          } else {
          set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
          }
     }


#   send all traffic to the default backend
    set req.backend_hint = default;

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
      req.method != "HEAD" &&
      req.method != "PUT" &&
      req.method != "POST" &&
      req.method != "TRACE" &&
      req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
      req.method != "PATCH" &&
      req.method != "DELETE") {
      return (pipe);
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
                return (pass);
    }

    if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
               return (pass);
    }


    return (hash);
}
```

httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080>
    ServerName coke.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.coke.domain.com domain.co.ke www.domain.co.ke
    DocumentRoot /home/vps/public_html/domain.co.ke
    ServerAdmin webmaster@coke.domain.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/coke.domain.com combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/coke.domain.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    ## User vps # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup vps vps
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup vps vps
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid vps vps
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
        #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
        AssignUserID vps vps
    </IfModule>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/vps/public_html/domain.co.ke/cgi-bin/
    Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_2/vps/coke.domain.com/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache/2.2.31 port 8080
varnish-4.1.2 revision 0d7404e port 80
SELinux is disabled

Mod_Security doesn't list any errors

I'm sending requests to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080, which the apache is listening on and my virtual hosts are configured with the same IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080.

And don't know where else to look.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you
d.

Comment: access directly to ip:8080 also reported 403 error? which user is apache running on? can you update your question by `ls -l /home/vps/public_html` to see current permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<Directory "/home/vps/public_html/domain.co.ke">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    # or
    # Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Mostly in httpd.conf/apache.conf the access is restricted.